# Disable cross-slide selection ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I would like to disable the cross-slide selection behavior for items in my ListView. I am aware of the property `IsSwipeEnabled="False"` however I still want to allow the user to drag and drop items into another Grid. I also tried capturing the Manipulation started / completed events with the following code.

```
MyListView.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsX;
MyListView.ManipulationStarted += OnManipulationStarted;
MyListView.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;
```

The appropriate events are caught in both handlers however I do not know what actions I should do to disable the selection to occur. I tried a similar approach I did for disabling right-clicking where I set the `RoutedEvents.Handled` to `true` but this does not prevent the selection from happening. Is there a clean way to handle this event and disable the selection to happen?

Comment: So you have set `IsSwipeEnabled="False"` and you still get selection happening? Or are you saying that you can't set it if you want to enable drag & drop?

Comment: That property is currently set to `True` in order to support drag & drop. Unfortunately this also allows the selection action of the cross slide to be enabled. Setting the property to `False` does not allow the drag & drop but disables the cross slide selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two things to try

1. Handle `SelectionChanged` events and deselect whatever got selected while otherwise allowing drag & drop to work naturally.
2. Do the above + disable swipe selection and handle drag & drop manually - set `MyListView.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsX | ManipulationModes.System`, handle manipulation events to initiate and handle drag & drop inputs, call [`CancelDirectManipulations()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.canceldirectmanipulations.aspx) on the dragged item container when you decide to switch from pan/scroll to drag&drop interaction, render a dragged item indicator in an adorner layer (just a panel on top of the `ListView` with some element attached to your finger), then handle drop on the drop target element.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Filip. I was hoping there was a cleaner way to disable this functionality however it seems like this might be the only way. The one thing I don't like about modifying the `SelectionChanged` events and removing items is how I have to determine whether the event prior to that was coming from a drag & drop or a cross-slide or an item click. Also the user will still see a Selection style being applied when the cross slide item is still being held down.

Comment: Maybe the selection style could be disabled through restyling `ListViewItems`... not sure about disabling the interactions though. Are you absolutely certain `IsSwipeEnabled` is required for built-in drag&drop?

Comment: I will look more into the styling attributes for the `ListViewItems` however right now I do not see specific attribute for when the selection is being held down within the select threshold. There might be a way to disable `IsSwipeEnabled` and still allow drag&drop (maybe dealing with the manipulation events) but I feel like I would have to add a lot more code for something that is almost implemented the way I need. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You don't need an attribute for that. You only need to edit the visual states.